# How do you write to the intermediary table generated by EF using unit of work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, http-post, entity, dto

question about REST APIs design in ASP.NET WEB API project - please excuse the long intro, just to explain the context. I have this in my controller, which works:

```
public void Post([FromBody] MovieUpdateDto movie) // is this a good Dto name?
{
     var movieToInsert = Mapper.Map<Movie>(movie);
    _unitOfWork.Movies.Add(movieToInsert);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

My question is: if there are related entities to Movies, such as director info (actually the `MovieUpdateDto` contains a `Directors` property of type  `ICollection<Director>`).

There are 2 subcases:

1. If the `Directors` already exists, I should also create entries in the `MovieDirectors` intermediary table which has two fields: `DirectorId` and `MovieId`. But how? There is no equivalent class in the C# code. This table was autogenerated by `Entity Framework 6`! Would I use an SqlCommand (I don't know if this would work outside of the configuration file and the approach would not be consistent with the rest of the method)?
2. If the `Directors` (one or several) don't exist, I should also (in addition to the above step 1) add the `Directors` information to the `Directors` table. So in this case the MovieUpdateDto would be a bit fatter and contain the Director Info.

Use case: in the UI I could have a checkbox: new director(s)? And if I check it, a new section in the form would reveal itself to add the `Directors` information.

So, I am thinking of doing it like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody] MovieUpdateDto movie) 
{

    var movieToInsert = Mapper.Map<Movie>(movie);
    if (movieToInsert.Directors != null) {
              _unitOfWork.Movies.Add(movieToInsert.Directors);
    }
    _unitOfWork.Movies.Add(movieToInsert);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Should I do it like this? Or should I have 2 Dtos and two Post methods for the two scenarios?

Also, I am not sure how I could write to the intermediary table MovieDirectors. Essentially there is no entity such called in the C# code. I do reference it in the MoviesConfiguration file like this:

```
HasMany(c => c.Directors)
    .WithMany(t => t.Movies)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("MovieDirectors");
        m.MapLeftKey("MovieId");
        m.MapRightKey("DirectorId");
    });
```

But there is no repository in the UnitOfWork file. I only have Repos there for the entities that have a match in C#, not for those auto-generated by EF.

For example:
`public class DirectorRepository : Repository<Director>, IDirectorRepository` is one such repository.

So how would I write to the `MovieDirectors` table?

PS. I am also thinking of maybe adding Directors separately and posting a movie separately, but when I post the movies, I still need to add some entries in that intermediary table.

**Also, when I write to that intermediate table, can I do it without having to save the previous changes to the two repositories? I will need the IDs of the previous entries, but can I manage without them, so I can fit everything in 1 big transaction?**

Update: Impressive! EF automatically writes to both the Directors table and the MovieDirectors table if I just insert records to Movies table. Now another problem: to recognise when some or all of the directors are already in the database and not insert any records for directors in those cases (to avoid having duplicates in the db).

Comment: Entity Framework is *already* an implementation of both the repository pattern and a Unit of Work. Don't unnecessarily wrap it in another abstraction when you already have precisely what you need.

Comment: `Should I do it like this?` did you try doing like this? Did it work,? Are you facing any issue in that?

Comment: Thank you, but this is probably a philosophical item open for debate. Suppose I want the repository pattern to decouple my application from any persistence frameworks...

Comment: Chetan, I didn't yet, I don't expect to encounter any issues, just posted that part for advice on whether it's a good design. But I am honestly much more concerned on how to write to the intermediary table, because I don't have a consistent approach there yet... I added a 'nuance' to the end of my OP.

Comment: Ok, it's possible that EF will automatically populate the junction table as well, I'll test that and return with a verdict.

Comment: PS. I added this as an update. Update: Impressive! EF automatically writes to both the Directors table and the MovieDirectors table if I just insert records to Movies table. Now another problem: to recognise when some or all of the directors are already in the database and not insert any records for directors in those cases (to avoid having duplicates in the db).